# Support for out parameters in Monotouch WCF

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios

I consume a WCF service with Monotouch using custom proxy creation and everything works fine. Nevertheless, it seems that there is not any support for out parameters. When an out parameter is used, always a null value is returned in the custom proxy implementation. Can you confirm that there is not any support for out parameters? Is there a roadmap for that?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2240. There is presently no roadmap for when it'll be fixed.

Comment: I think the aforementioned link presents the issue in a little hazy manner. Anyway, this is definitely not a Minor importance!